# Doctrine two type entities relationship many to many to single entity

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to make a relantionship between User Or Group Entity via Joining table to Single Entity Permissions like many to many just left side has two entities

[image: graph]

It's similar to many to many relationship

The idea is to access User->getPermissions() or Group->getPermissions() via single join table to the get All permissions

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Currently I have made a simple table for joining with two left side ids and one right side like group_id, user_id, permissions_id

Comment: Group->getPermissions() should return a single User's permissions and the groups permissions? Is that the goal?

Comment: No, Group will return group permission, on user it will return specific user permissions

Comment: Could you provide your mapping code? Base on this definition it's possible we have a group id in join table and the user id be NULL in the join table, right?